# Jupyter Notebook HTML cell magic with Python variable

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to figure out if there is anyway to do HTML cell magic using a python variable

```
myvar = "<a href='somelink'>"

%%html
myvar
```

This of course just outputs `myvar` rather than the html. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Not with the magic, but `IPython.display.HTML(myvar)` should work. It creates a displayable object, so put that at the end of a cell, or pass it to `IPython.display.display()`.

Comment: that worked, thanks!